# Is there a specific function within Google Sheets that will allow me to pull a range of data from multiple worksheets within the same workbook?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For the use case that I'm working on, we're trying to pull the row of data starting at month 8/1/2021. Then repeats where ever 8/1/2021 is seen, capturing the list of values below. For example, Within one workbook a list per user will display dates and values range from the beginning of the month to the end. We want to capture everything starting at the beginning to then end the starting over when 8/1/2021 is shown again. But only capturing values not dates, column 2) for each user compiling in one-sheets constantly.

Example Google Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QGUqvLZP2yjdiXhjKo2pxoGFeyORemI_OdYYuV2XEz8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Link is updated

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({'User 1'!A2:F; 'User 2'!A2:F; 'User 3'!A2:F}, "where Col1 is not null")
```

[image]